# Two incorrect translations on the French version of Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

## Apps & Software

Here is the *Apps & Software* part in English:

> [image: Apps & Software]

Here is the same part on the French version:

> [image: Applications et logiciels]

The word *application* has been incorrectly translated to *candidature*. The french word *candidature* can be translated as *candidacy* or *application*. But a *candidature* is an *application* for a **job** or a **loan**, so the translation is wrong in this context.

I suggest that you use **ajouter une application...** or **ajouter un logiciel...**.

## Background

Here is the *Background* part in English:

> [image: Background]

Here is the same part on the French version:

> [image: Arrière-plan]

Once again, the translation is incorrect because of the context: an *arrière-plan* is a *background* but only in the context of an image or a landscape. If you ask a French person what his *arrière-plan* is, he will probably look behind him to see his background.

My suggestion is **Contexte** (as written in the description text), it may not be the best word to express the idea of the *background* but with the text below it will be perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sacrebleu !*

The word *application* is now correctly translated as per your suggestion (*ajouter une application*)

The *Background* section has been translated to *Plus d'informations*, which is probably not perfect either but encourages the user to fill the section with extra info.

Thank you for your report and your suggestions!

Comment: I love the space before your `!` :)

Comment: I suggest *Davantage d'informations* or *Informations complémentaires* instead of *Plus d'informations* because *Plus d'informations* is ambiguous, it can be understood as *More information* or *No more information* (*Plus [aucune] information*).